# Switch to parent shell without logging out

Tags: shell

Let's say I start in my local account:

```
avindra@host:~>
```

then I switch to root:

```
host:~ #
```

Then I switch to oracle:

```
[ oracle@host:~]
```

Is there a way for me to drop back into the root shell (the parent), without logging out of the oracle shell?

This would be convenient, because the oracle account **does not** have sudo privileges. A typical scenario with oracle is that I end up in /some/really/deeply/nested/directory, and all kinds of special environment variables are set in particular ways.

Here comes the problem: I need to get back into root to touch some system files. Yes, I can log out of oracle to get back to root, but at the cost of losing my current working directory and environment.

Is there a way to "switch" to the parent shell using known conventions?

Comment: If you are using a gui desktop, you can just open another terminal window or tab or even switch to another virtual console. If not, use screen as stated in one of the answers.

Comment: I'll look into screen, I haven't used it before. As for tabs, I prefer to use one tab for host. I find a workflow that entails multiple tabs per host to be cumbersome. I do a lot of work in clustered hosts / distributed systems,  so even having one tab per node in the cluster can get confusing. In my mind, one tab = one discrete host.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can simulate a `CTRL-Z` (which you normally use to temporarily background a process) using the `kill` command:

```
[tsa20@xxx01:/home/tsa20/software]$ kill -19 $$

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo -iu tsa20
[root@xxx01 ~]# fg
sudo -iu tsa20
[tsa20@xxx01:/home/tsa20/software]$
```

`bash` just traps the `CTRL-Z` key combination. `kill -19` sends `SIGSTP` to the process which is effectively the same thing.

Comment: In `zsh` you can just run `suspend`.

Comment: @Mikel, `zsh` or `csh`, `tcsh`, or `bash`, or the Bourne shell or `ksh`... (in `ksh`, _suspend is an alias for `'kill -s STOP $$'`_ (note the bug with the missing quotes around $$)).

Comment: I can't run `suspend` after doing a `sudo -i` ([Output](https://dpaste.de/oSS8)) in bash.

Comment: Just reproduced [the same error message](https://dpaste.de/vki5) in `zsh`. Adding `-f` makes it work though.

Comment: Beautiful. This is going to save me so much time. Can't wait to show it to the coworkers.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Does that really make a difference with a variable that's almost certainly guaranteed to contain a numeric value?

Comment: @nyuszika7h, not-quoting variables is the split+glob operator. It makes no sense at all to invoke it here. The behaviour of the split part depends on the current value of `$IFS`. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22565).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `$$` is a read-only variable, though, and you can make assumptions about its value. That said, I **do** quote those variables when using them.

Comment: `bash` does _not_ trap CTRL-Z, when you press CTRL-Z, your terminal emulator sends a `^Z` character (0x1a) to the master side of the pty device. The _line discipline_ of the pty driver then sends SIGTSTP to the foreground process group of the terminal. Until then `bash` is not involved at all. That SIGTSTP may cause the process group leader to suspend and _then_ the `wait()` that `bash` does on it will return.

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that `19` will be the number of SIGTSTP. Use `kill -s TSTP` or `kill -s STOP` (TSTP can be trapped or ignored, STOP cannot).

Comment: @nyuszika7h, `$$` may be readonly, but `IFS` is not. Try `IFS=0123456789; suspend` in `ksh` for instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I didn't think of that. That's a good point.

Answer (score 3):

Csh, bash, ksh, zsh, have a `suspend` builtin command (or alias, in ksh) that does exactly that. This command is mostly equivalent to sending a TSTP signal to the shell; bash and zsh do a bit of additional signal handler and juggling, and in these shells the `suspend` command works even if the shell is currently ignoring TSTP.

You can also send the signal to the shell manually with `kill -STOP $$`.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest that you could use (install if needed) a program called `[screen][1]` that let's you have multiple terminal windows open. It was designed for TTYS so it works just fine without needing `X`. You can use keyboard shortcuts to switch between terminals and disconnect and logout, leaving your terminals still running, then log back in and reconnect to them.

I believe most Linux distributions have packages for this program, and I have used packages on Solaris for it. Worst case of course is you can install from source.

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a comment rather than an anaswer.